# Is there a way to tell what image was used to deploy a machine from Windows Deployment Services?

Tags: wds, hash

Is there a way to tell what image was used to deploy a machine from Windows Deployment Services?  Is there some sort of a hash that would identify a machine being deployed from a particular image?